# Textbox with autocomplete on jQuery in ASP.NET MVC 3 aspplication view doesn't look as expected

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

The code of my input field:

```
<input type="text" id = "selectedTenderName" name="selectedTenderName" />
```

And here I add references to js files:

```
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.14.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#selectedTenderName").autocomplete({ source: "/Reports/QuickSearch" });
});
```

The code of action:

```
public ActionResult QuickSearch(string term)
    var tenders = db.TENDERS
            .Where(t => t.NAMERU.ToLower().Contains(term.ToLower()))
            .Take(10)
            .OrderBy(t => t.NAMERU)
            .Select(t => new { label = t.NAMERU });
    return Json(tenders, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

The first image - view that I want to do.

[image]

The second - view that I make.

[image]

Where is the problem and what should I do?

Comment: It looks like your CSS that is styling the dropdown either is not included correctly/at all, or the selector(s) are not correct.

Comment: You need core and UI <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.core.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> <link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.theme.css")" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

Answer (score 1):

Have you included the jQuery UI stylesheet reference in your page?

Answer (score 0):

You should be okay if you add the JQueryUI stylesheet to your page.

This should work:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.13/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
```

In case you didn't know, Microsoft offers a free CDN for Javascript libraries that they include with .Net MVC. You can get more information here:

http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/cdn.ashx

But the short version is that you should be able to add:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.14/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.14/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

And get all that you want, plus let Microsoft host it for you.

We've paid them plenty, nice to get something free just this once.